# local variable as non-type argument, with template specification

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a template function, and template specifications on an enum. I want the program to choose the template specification based on the value of enum at runtime. Is it possible?

Following code got error:

```
error C2971: 'Func' : template parameter 'fruit' : 'fruit' : a local variable cannot be used as a non-type argument
```

Code:

```
enum class Fruit
{
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Count
};

template<Fruit>
void Func()
{}

template<>
void Func<Fruit::Apple>()
{
    std::cout << "Apple" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void Func<Fruit::Orange>()
{
    std::cout << "Orangle" << std::endl;
}

void Foo(Fruit fruit)
{
    Func<fruit>(); // error C2971: 'Func' : template parameter 'fruit' : 'fruit' : a local variable cannot be used as a non-type argument
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Foo(Fruit::Apple);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the program to choose the template specification based on the value of enum at runtime.

No, that is not possible. Template non-type arguments must be available at compile time. If you don't have your value until runtime, you can only pass it in as a function argument.

What you *can* do, as TC suggests, is `switch` on all possible values, and explicitly calling `Func` with what are compile time constant literals:

```
void Foo(Fruit fruit)
{
    switch (fruit) {
    case Fruit::Apple:
        Func<Fruit::Apple>();
        break;
    case Fruit::Orange:
        Func<Fruit::Orange>();
        break;
    // .. maybe other fruits here
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's possible (`switch` on the runtime argument and call the appropriate instantiation).

Comment: does anything change with C++23?